# Extending Entities in Symfony with relationships carried over

Tags: symfony, relationship, abstract-class, entity-relationship, extends

I am trying to extend one of my Entities (Class A) in my Symfony Doctrine, it is working well but when I try to update the schema to create the new Entity (Class B) I am missing some fields from the extended Entity Class (Class A).

There are two Many-To-One relationships in the parent class (Class A), that I am trying to extend which are being emitted from the new Entity (Class B).

Here is one of the relationships in Class A that should be carried over:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\LessonSectionActivity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $lessonSectionActivity;
```

Variables like this are fine and are picked up by Class B:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $score;
```

I have tried directly placing the relationships in the entity file of the new class (Class B) but there is still no doctrine update carrying over these relationships. Do I need to make an entire new Entity with a Repository or is there a way to carry over these relationships?

Comment: afaik you would use a "MappedSuperClass" to extend from, see https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/inheritance-mapping.html which is not an entity itself though

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if implemented correctly, check : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritance-mapping